# unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError) - ruby on rails error while starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

My rails application throws this error on start. What are the possible causes for this?

```
c:\test_install>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/win32/registry.rb:70:in `find': unkno
wn encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/win32/registry.rb:70:in
`<module:Win32>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/win32/registry.rb:3:in `
<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/win32/resolv.rb:6:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:170:in `<class
:Hosts>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:167:in `<class
:Resolv>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:37:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.
rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0
.pre.1/lib/bundler/gem_remote_fetcher.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0
.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0
.pre.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:135:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from c:/test_install/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
c:\test_install>gem install rails
```

Comment: Have you installed the Ruby [DevKit](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/)?

Comment: what version of rails?

Comment: after making new file and try (rails server)  i cant get the url

Comment: rails 4.2.5.1version

Comment: This is going to be the first of many windows related problems you run into. You're better off starting all over again and installing a virtualization environment (Vagrant + Virtualbox).

Answer (score 7):

**Codepage 720** is Arabic characters used by MS-DOS .

It is recommended that you switch your terminal code page to something Ruby understands, like the windows 1252 character encoding of the Latin alphabet.

You problem could be solved through this command

```
chcp 1252
```

A much better way is to permanently force the terminal to use the right code page, i.e by using a batch like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8/685264#685264).

Moreover, it is preferrable to use Linux with [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) for ruby on rails developer.